# Awk, Colour, and Audio

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

If I pipe data into `awk` and print, say, the second column like `... | awk '{print $2}'` which then returns integer values is it possible to do the following on the returned numerical values:

- Colour them when they fall below and above a threshold
- Turn a sound on and off depending on which side of that threshold the values sit

I have also experimented with the command `watch -n <secs> <my command> | awk '{print $2}'` so that I don't have to keep running the one liner (which is ideally how this will end up) but for whatever reason this doesn't output anything.

I am primarily concerned with the first two questions. I'll then try to work out how to use it with `watch`.

Comment: You need to use some quotes in your `watch` command: `watch "cmd | awk '{print $2}'" should work. What kind of sound are you looking for?

Comment: `watch` isn't really designed for piping, but if all you want to do is run some command repeatedly through awk, you can do it like this: `awk < <(while <my command>; do sleep <secs>; done) '{print $2}'`. That will stop if the command fails but you can easily modify the loop to continue regardless.

Answer (score 1):

For the color part you can do like this:

```
cat file
10
20
30
40
```

```
awk '$1>20 { $1="\033[1;34m"$1"\033[0m\007"}1' file
10
20
30
40
```

Here `30` and `40` will be printed in blue color, since the are larger than `20`
The `\007` gives one beep if there is one true hit (thanks Ed for this)

Comment: and for the sound you could just print a control-G (bel, `\007`). See http://www.unixwerk.eu/unix/ansicodes.html.

Comment: Would this be singular or repetitive audio?

Comment: @uncle-junky I think the control-g gives only one ping. Not sure if you can make it some repetitive to give more sound.

Comment: one control-G = one ping. 1,000 control-Gs = really annoying :-). You can always write a shell loop to sleep N secs and then beep but what behavior are you hoping for?